# Is "みかさ" a synonym for Tangerine or Mandarin (orange)

Tags: words

I took 3 years of Japanese starting in 1996. A lot has obviously worn off in the last 20 years, but one word that really stuck out was "Mikasa". I swear I saw that it was the word for tangerine or mandarin orange, and it was repeatedly drilled in because my parents have Mikasa brand dinnerware/flatware. I was going to relay that info to a friend who is into anime (because he mentioned Mikasa Ackermann from *Attack on Titan*), but when I double checked to make sure I didn't look like an idiot, I came up with nothing.

I see that みかん is the word for mandarin orange. Is みかさ some sort of alternative word or brand of fruit or something, and I don't have the right Google-fu to find it?

Comment: Mi Casa, Tu Casa?  My umbrella is your umbrella??

Comment: Where I grew up, we used to call *dorayaki* by that name. I didn’t know that famous sweet in Doraemon was the same thing as *mikasa* till much later.

Comment: Any chance you mistook an orange volleyball for fruit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me personally, I have never seen or heard the word "Mikasa" used to refer to oranges. I was born and spent a lot of time in Japan, but I have never heard of the word "Mikasa" except for:

- [A company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikasa_Sports)
- [Mikasa city in Hokkaido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikasa,_Hokkaido)
- [The mountain in Nara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Wakakusa) and [the battleship named after it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_battleship_Mikasa)
- The anime character you mentioned
- And lastly, the names of people, and a family of [Imperial house of Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_House_of_Japan).

I did a bit of googling to make sure my knowledge was correct, but it seems that the word Mikasa is never used for oranges. I think you may have misremembered something.

Comment: Mandela Effect?

Comment: @istrasci `The Mandela Effect refers to a situation in which a large mass of people believes that an event occurred when it did not...` *large mass of people*?